# How to call multiple buttons click using single button click

Tags: asp.net, button

In my single page two buttons are there. one button is using 3 tier structure to insert data in to database and it is perfectly running.

Button coding

```
 <asp:Button ID="InsertButton1" CssClass="BUTT" runat="server"   OnClick="Insert" CommandName="Insert"  Text="SUBMIT" />
```

second button code

```
  <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">

        <InsertItemTemplate>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
 Office Address
 </td>

<td>
  <asp:TextBox ID="office_addressTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("office_address") %>' />
</td>

  </tr>


    <tr>
   <td>
   Date Of Birth
       </td>

 <td>
 <asp:TextBox ID="dobTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dob") %>' />

  </td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
   Sex
   </td>
   <td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="SexTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Sex") %>' /> 
    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton"  runat="server" CausesValidation="true"  CommandName="Insert" Text="insert" />
           </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</InsertItemTemplate>

    </asp:FormView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"
         ConnectionString="Data Source=WIN-MIUHU8FBDQI\PANKIL;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"


         InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [research] ([office_address], [dob], [Sex]) VALUES
         (@office_address, @dob, @Sex)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
         ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" >

        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="office_address" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="dob" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Sex" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

i want that when any one click on one button , second button also perform a insert task.

Comment: ... that's not how buttons work. You should solve that by separating the actual actions happening in the code behind from the click event handlers instead, then you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure if there is a way to trigger that in asp. But i think JQuery can do that for you.

However a neater way to do it as stated by @Luaan is calling the click event and handle it in the cs code. This way it promotes reuse of codes and no update/change of codes problems.

asp page:

```
   <asp:Button ID="FirstButton" CssClass="BUTT" runat="server" OnClick="onclick="button1_Click"  Text="SUBMIT" />
 <asp:Button ID="SecondButton" CssClass="BUTT" runat="server" OnClick="onclick="button2_Click"  Text="SUBMIT" />
```

Here in the cs code you handle the event.

I think you want this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2_Click(sender, e);
}
```

However a neater way would be this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InsertIntoDatabase();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InsertIntoDatabase();
}

private void InsertIntoDatabase()
{
    // Your Insert into Database codes here
}
```

So any adjustment to your insert query can be in the method InsertIntoDatabase().

Comment: I did as you guide me. can you say me that How to call buttons in private void InsertIntoDatabase()
{
    // Your Insert into Database codes here
}

Comment: private void button click event will auto fire when you click on a button, it will then proceed to call InsertIntoDatabase Method. What software are you using? asp.net?